# How to handle multiple components in a loop with React-Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am working on a simple react-redux application. And I need my user to upload 2 or 5 files (depending on the user type). Let's say he can be either a simple user or an admin, the user has to upload 2 file and an admin 5. I use react-dropzone to upload my files

From my database I get an object with an array of object, it returns something like:

```
user: {
    name: "John Doe",
    docs: [
     {
         url: "http://path-to-image.png"
     },
     {
         url: "http://path-to-image2.png"
     }
    ]
}
```

To simplify, in my application I have a Container.js, a Component.js, and in the component i iterate in the docs array by doing a map, and then for each doc I render a new item, let's say FileItem.

The problem is more in the way to upload the files than how to handle the files from the database.

On each file I want to set some booleans in order to know if the user has chosen a picture and if the picture is submitting to the database.

So my actions look like this for now:

```
function changePictureA(picture){
    return {
        type: ADD_PICTURE_A,
        picture: picture,
        isPictureChanged: true,
        isPictureSubmitting: false
    }
}

export function changeFirstPicture(file){
    return function(dispatch){
        dispatch(changePictureA(file[0]));
    }
}
```

This works well and I can see my action being dispatched but for now I have set this logic in the FileItem component. But like this file is going to be called several times (2 or 5 according to user's type), this logic can't be in this file right ?

What I really want to know is if I have to set all my values in my container, that mean to write something like this :

```
function mapStateToProps(state){
    const { picture,isPictureChanged, isPictureSubmitting} = state.pictureAReducer;
    return {
        picture,
        isPictureChanged,
        isPictureSubmitting
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(KycItem);
```

So this is for one Item, if I have 5, I will have to do it 5 times and to have 5 reducers just for this ? Is that the best solution ? I mean, I will have to set long name variables like you can see whereas I would have prefer to just have `isSubmitting, isChanged`.

I hope your answers will help me !

Answer (score 0):

This perfectly fits into [redux todo list sample](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/ExampleTodoList.html). Instead of creating reducers and controls for every separate picture you can just add id to the picture and use general actions:

```
function changePictureAction(id, picture){
    return {
        type: ADD_PICTURE,
        id: id,
        picture: picture,
        isPictureChanged: true,
        isPictureSubmitting: false
    }
}

export function changePicture(id, file){
    return function(dispatch){
        dispatch(changePictureAction(id, file[id]));
    }
}
```

Then you need to split [Presentation and Container](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html#presentational-and-container-components), on the presentation you need to have FileItem and FileItemsList, while Container handles all data binding logic:

// Container

```
import changePicture from './PictureActions'
import FileItemsList from './FileItemsList'

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        pictures: state.pictures
    }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return { changePicture }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(FileItemsList);
```

// FileItemsList.js

```
const FileItemsList = ({pictures, changePicture}) => {
  const fileitems = pictures.map(pic =>
    <FileItem key={pic.id} picture={pic.picture}
              onChange={(picture)=>changePicture(pic.id, picture)}/>)

  return <div>{fileitems}</div>
}

export default FileItemsList
```

Also you will need to add upload handlers and dispatchers